# How to append two files as a single file - on click button

Tags: apex

I have two attachments to an object in salesforce(.txt format). I would like to know if any chance to add those two files data and create a single .txt file . I know that we can do it in Java. Is it possible to do it in salesforce( by click on a button)

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Create a Visualforce page with the relevant object as the standard controller and a controller extension. Give the page an action, so a function that is called on page load. In that function, load the body of both of the Attachments, and create a new one with the content of both appended. Becuase you've used the standard controller, you can create a button on the object and add that to the standard Salesforce form.

Comment: Do you have any sample code to approach your suggestions. Please help

Comment: There are plenty of code samples available, if you have a specific coding question, please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grab the two files, convert the body fields to strings, and add them together.

```
Attachment a = new Attachment(Body=EncodingUtil.base64Decode('SGVsbG8g'));
Attachment b = new Attachment(Body=EncodingUtil.base64Decode('V29ybGQh'));
System.debug(a.Body.toString()+b.Body.toString());
```

This only works if they are truly text files; files designed to be opened in Microsoft Word, for example, are actually binary files, as are PDF files. You could only combine the files if they can be read properly in Notepad.

Comment: They are pure text file with .txt format. Also I am able to open the file and read it in notepad. Can you please provide me how to approach it though a button. means when I click on a button it should be read both files data and create a single txt file.            Also is there anyway I can attach the files here so that it will be helpful to understand it

Comment: @KSL There's a lot of ways to make buttons that you could use, like a JavaScript button, a VisualForce page with a button, a Lightning component, a flow... it all depends on how you want the UX to be.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I will approach your suggestion by going with Java script button and test the functionality. Will get back here once I complete the test. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In part, it depends on how they're stored. If they're stored as blobs, as noted in comments, you'll need to render them on a visualforce page first. If they're stored as a text file, then you should be able to use a controller and string methods to append one to the other and save the result. Optionally, you could even use JS and/or JS Remoting. Needless to say, there are numerous methods to do this.

It largely depends on what form the data is currently in. Most attachments tend to be stored as blobs but often they'll be stored using Base64 or other encoding which would allow you to do it within a class without the need for a visualforce page to convert it to text for you. You'd just use the decryption methods found in the Apex Documention.

Comment: Below is one of the rows in my text file 00000012300000761830000003637100000630000